# Why does my RecyclerView shows the same value every iteration?

Tags: android, json, kotlin, android-recyclerview

It shows the correct number of objects, but gives them all the same value.

Background:
I am following a tut to build a Slack-like app. I am using the recycler view to show the list of channels.

This is my adapter

```
class ChannelsAdapter(val context: Context, val channels: ArrayList<Channel>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<ChannelsAdapter.Holder>() {

    inner class Holder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val singleChannel = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.single_channel)

        fun bindText(textVar: String, context: Context) {
            singleChannel.text = textVar
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: Holder, position: Int) {
        holder.bindText(channels[position].toString(), context)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return channels.count()
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): Holder {

        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.channel_list_layout, parent, false)
        return Holder(view)

    }
}
```

This is the "channel" class:

```
class Channel(val name: String, val Description: String, val id: String) {

    override fun toString(): String {
        return ("#$name")
    }

}
```

This is the variable the data that is being assigned to the RecyclerView, and the functions that pulls the data from the server and

```
object MessageService {

    val channels = ArrayList<Channel>()

    fun getChannels(context: Context, complete: (Boolean) -> Unit) {

        val channelsRequest =
            object : JsonArrayRequest(Method.GET, URL_GET_CHANNELS, null, Response.Listener { response ->

                try {

                    for (x in 0 until (response.length())) {
                        val channel = response.getJSONObject(0)
                        val channelName = channel.getString("name")
                        val channelDescription = channel.getString("description")
                        val channelId = channel.getString("_id")

                        val newChannel = Channel(channelName, channelDescription, channelId)
                        this.channels.add(newChannel)

                    }
                    complete(true)

                } catch (e: JSONException) {
                    Log.d("JSON", "EXC:" + e.localizedMessage)
                    complete(false)
                }

            }, Response.ErrorListener {
                Log.d("ERROR", "Could not retrieve channels")
                complete(false)
            }) {

                override fun getBodyContentType(): String {
                    return "application/json; charset=utf-8"
                }

                override fun getHeaders(): MutableMap<String, String> {
                    val headers = HashMap<String, String>()

                    headers.put("Authorization", "Bearer ${AuthService.authToken}")
                    return headers
                }
            }

        Volley.newRequestQueue(context).add(channelsRequest)

    }

}
```

This val gets its data from the server as a JsonArray.

Comment: May be try to use `size()` instead of `count()` in `getItemCount()`

Comment: @Maxouille the count() works fine, it is the data that isn't showing properly

Comment: Try to print the value of `textVar` inside the `bindText()` method to see if it changes.
Anyway, you should look at the android doc on how to implement a custom recyclerview in kotlin : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview#kotlin
Try to write you recyclerview as the example to see if it works better.

Comment: I've implemented custom recyclerView adapters a couple of times already, and have been comparing this to the others I've made, but I really can't find what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I can just advice you to print your arrayList as well as `textVar` in the `bondText()` method to see what's going on.
You can post the log here

Answer (score 1):

Just change your `onBindViewHolder` like this

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: Holder, position: Int) {
        holder.bindText(channels[position], context)
    }
```

And your `bindText` function like this

```
inner class Holder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val singleChannel = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.single_channel)

        fun bindText(data: Channel, context: Context) {
            singleChannel.text = data.name
        }
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't help

Comment: @Tsabary now what problem you are facing ?

Answer (score 0):

Check where you are initializing Chanel and passing in the channels list. Make sure each channel is initialized inside the loop that appends the Channel into the list. Happened to me a while back e.g

```
   while(true) {
   Channel myChanel= new Channel()
   myChanel.name = "name"
   channels.add(myChanel)
   } 
// Pass list into adapter. Convert to kotlin :)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm not using a loop at all actually so not sure if that helps.

Comment: Sorry Philip my mistake, there was a loop being used and it is already being initialized inside it.

Comment: Try logging the ` newChannel.name ` right after it's added to the channels arraylist. Just to be sure the loop is working as expected. Sorry for the late reply.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was in the loop pulling the information from the server, foolish mistake.

```
for (x in 0 until (response.length())) {
                        val channel = response.getJSONObject(0)
                        val channelName = channel.getString("name")
                        val channelDescription = channel.getString("description")
                        val channelId = channel.getString("_id")
```

I kept pulling object "0" instead of "x"